# How to convert queryparameters to string in angular4

Tags: angular, url, router, encode, query-string

I have object like below:

```
 const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: {
    serviceName: 'someName',
    serviceId: 5,
    businessAreaId: 1,
    servicePhaseVersionId: 5,
    versionDescription: 'Version 1',
    phaseName: 'SomePhase',
    mode: 1
```

and I'm navigating like below:

```
this.router.navigate(['someUrl/'], navigationExtras);
```

After navigation in the browser I see URl like this:

```
http://localhost:4000/someUrl/version?serviceName=someName&serviceId=5&businessAreaId=1&servicePhaseVersionId=5&versionDescription=Version%201&phaseName=SomePhase&mode=1
```

Is there any possibility to get string with parameters like in browser's URL or below?

```
'serviceName=someName&serviceId=5&businessAreaId=1&servicePhaseVersionId=5&versionDescription=Version%201&phaseName=SomePhase&mode=1'
```

Comment: you want to get a whole string with params or individual params?

Comment: whole string exactly like in last code sample

Answer (score 0):

Use **params**

inject the dependencies:

1. ActivatedRouter

Since params returns an Observable, you will need to subscribe to it to get the parameters.

```
 constructor(private _activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        this._activateRoute.params.subscribe((params) => this.activateComponent(params));
   }
```